# Started getting EventStructWrongData warning in my ERC20 Token Code

Tags: solidity, etherscan

I suddenly started getting  EventStructWrongData (very low-severity) warning in my Ethereum code in Etherscan. It was not there before, so how come it started showing up all of a sudden?

This is the code: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x42a5740f1e7efd2337171db355d8bf4a6e232e15#code

This is the error:

[image]

The funny thing is that I have not used Struct anywhere in the contract. So, how come it says Struct used in event will have some problem?

Comment: I assume it's a newly-discovered bug (why it just started showing up), and this warning shows for anything compiled with a version of the compiler that has the bug.